# Function that prints the location of all the vertices of an active object

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, vertices, vertex-groups

I want to write a function that prints the location of all of the vertices of an active object.

I have a Cube and I want to print out the location of the 8 vertices of the cube.
I started doing this but I dont really know what I am doing.

```
def printVertices() :
       Cube = bpy.context.active_object
       lemesh = obj.data
       print(lesmesh.vertices[0].co.x)
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question many times. If you are not getting 
answers, or the answers don’t help, then **edit your original post** with 
more information and detailing what you have tried that is not working. 
Read: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your object is selected, the following code should work:

```
import bpy

for vert in bpy.context.active_object.data.vertices:
    print (vert.co)
```

I will also point out blender has an integrated terminal where you can type incomplete python statements (e.g `bpy.context.active_object.data.`) and press `tab` in order to print a display of the possible completions. This is very useful to quickly navigate over the properties of bpy objects and gain quick intuition on what you can and can't do.